# If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix with $(A-I)^2=0$ then which of the following is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix with $(A-I)^2=0$ then which of the following is true?

$1.$ $A=I$

$2.$ $\det(A)=1$

$3.$ $\operatorname{trace}(A)=n$

I have counter example for the first option.For $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ take
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

About other options I have no idea.I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: once again, the Normal form of Jordan is the solution (and the origin) to all the problems in linear algebra

Comment: @Exodd sorry but I do not understand what are you saying.

Comment: **Hint**: What can we say about the determinant of $A-I$? The eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I think now I got it,$A-I$ is nilpotent matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(A-I)^2=0\;$ implies that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ (you can see this through his minimal polynomial, or a lot of other ways).
It means that his Jordan Form has all the elements in the diagonal equal to one.

Since trace and determinant are invariant by similarity, you have thate $trace(A)=n$, $det(A)=1$

Answer (score 3):

Since $(X-1)^2$ only has$~1$ as root, the characteristic polynomial of$~A$ must be $\chi_A=(X-1)^n$. In particular the trace of $A$ (minus the coefficient of $X^{n-1}$ in $\chi_A$) is$~n$ and the determinant of$~A$ ($(-1)^n$ times the constant coefficient of$~\chi_A$) is$~1$.